# Clear first line jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

How do I clean or remove the first line in a JTextArea?

I have used so far

```
int start = 0;
                     int end = 131;
                     area.replaceRange (null, start, end);
```

but it is also obsolete as a method of JTextArea text is dynamic so this is not good.

Answer (score 16):

Use:

```
int end = textArea.getLineEndOffset(0) 
textArea.replaceRange("", 0, end);
```